# Metadata edit bar disappeared in Arc Catalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, arccatalog, toolbar

could anybody help me? in my Arc Catalog the edit bar for Metadata disappeared. 
In my Catalog it looks like this:

[image]

But this ist from Esri website, it should look like this:

[image]

How can I add this Editing bar?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the ArcCatalog settings? Delete or rename your "normal.gxt", this is in your user profile folders, for instance:

C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work :-( We use a concurrent user license so I checked if the other PC has the same problem. And it has. So I think the Problem is not on my PC but maybe on the server. But I have no clue how to change that.